# Red text after "/". Make unreadable

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C90ER.png)

i use Python and Visual Studio Code IDE

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You need to use \\

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes in strings are ”escape characters” used to signify special characters such as newline (`\n`), tab (`\t`), and so on.

To put an actual backslash in a string, use a double backslash: `this\\that`, or use an `r-string`: `r”this\that”`.